# setting read_excel to guess some column types

Tags: r

I use `read_excel` from `readxl` package to read a file where 3 of the columns I want to coerce as text, and the rest I'm happy to let `read_excel` guess the type. Can I do this?

I tried using `col_type` setting the columns I want to be `text` and the rest as `blank`, but this results in the `blank` columns being skipped. I tried using `NA` instead of `blank`, but that coerces the columns all to `text` whereas `read_excel` otherwise would have read some as `numeral.

My code was

```
col_filter <- rep('blank', 14)
col_filter[1, 3, 7] <- 'text'
read_excel(file, sheet, col_type=col_filter)
```

14 is the number of columns in the excel file, 1 3 7 are the columns I want to read as text. Bonus if I can do this without knowing in advance the number of columns (short of reading the file once first just to check the number of columns).

Comment: Why not start with `col_filter <- rep('numeric', 14)`?

Comment: Because there a few `date`s in the columns as well?

Comment: The `fread` function in data.table pkg has guessing-logic for types.

Comment: can `fread` read `.xlsx` instead of `.csv` ?

Comment: You also might check out `read.xlsx` in xlsx package, it has some facility for specifying some of the column classes.

Comment: That would be a sort-of-last-resort, because I actually just began porting all my codes from `read.xlsx` to `readxl`.

Comment: I think read.xls ports perl-code that makes an intermediate csv file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
col_filter <- readxl:::xlsx_col_types(path = file, n = 100,nskip = 1)
col_filter[1, 3, 7] <- 'text'
read_excel(file, sheet, col_type=col_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can specify `col_types` as a character vector, one entry per column. See https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html

There is a feature request for more fine-grained control over individual columns: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/198, https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/571